# Facebook 'Send' button not sending url; not telling me why

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a facebook 'Send' button that is supposed to allow a users to post one of my blog posts on my rails-based site to a facebook feed.

This is the real url that I'm trying to post:
`http://50.62.12.222/projects/1/blog_posts/1/blog_post_replies`

At first I thought it might be an issue with authentication for that particular object's 'show' action. Once I fixed that and verified that the page does not require authentication, I am baffled about what to try next.

neither the route `<%= project_blog_post_blog_post_replies_url(@project, b) %>` or the rendered url(above) work. And the error I'm getting in equally ambiguous:

```
"We encountered the following error when sending your message:"
```

EDIT: And I get the same failure if I try this url on the facebook developer site as well (where it gives you the paste code for the button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting og meta tags too. Although the are not required fields, but facebook might be failing initial requests for Send button hit. Consider following suggestions

Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Tiny og:image:  All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification.

Once you are done, go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F50.62.12.222%2Fprojects%2F1%2Fblog_posts%2F1%2Fblog_post_replies and ensure you are doing everything fine.

Comment: Ah. The trick was that it really wanted the title and url in the header. Obnoxious. Why can't I just send a url.